# How to add Open Source files to my app in Eclipse?

Tags: android, dialog, implementation

just wanted to add this Color Picker ( http://code.google.com/p/devmil-android-color-picker/source/browse/ ) to my app and make it appear when a preference is clicked, but my problem is how to add it? Where should I copy that folders? I have this,  so what should I put inside?

```
Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener colordialog = new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener(){
    public Boolean OnPreferenceClick(Preference preference){
        if (preference.getKey().equals("color")){

                      }
                return false;}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The project seems to be an Android Library project
2. The source control seems to be [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/). If you have a Mercurial plugin for Eclipse, you can use that to import the project to Eclipse from the project's repository at http://code.google.com/p/devmil-android-color-picker/source/checkout
3. Once you have imported the project, you need to refer it in your project as mentioned in Referencing a Library project section of [Managing Projects from Eclipse with ADT](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html)

Comment: Should I Have to install Mercurial?? I already have Eclipse + ADT installed

Comment: "Where should I copy that folders?" - i hope you are already downloaded the project. Are't you?

Comment: @BamsBamx You need either the [Mercurial plugin](http://www.javaforge.com/project/HGE) or a Mercurial client. Plugin would be the easiest to use.

Comment: thanks I found a tutorial in spanish http://blog.freniche.com/2011/06/18/instalar-el-plugin-de-mercurial-en-eclipse/

Comment: ok, i have mercurial pluging installed, but nnow how do i import the project there are too many options ;)

Comment: File > Import > Mercurial > Clone Existing Mercurial Repository. Next> Give the repository URL (`https://code.google.com/p/devmil-android-color-picker/`) and proceed

Comment: thanks!!! it worked! now, after assigning this library to my project how should i call it??? i mean, I have a button, so i want to set a clicklistener and when clicked open the dialog..how to do it??? thanks :P!!!

Comment: Use `ColorSelectorDialog` like you would normally use a `Dialog`. If you have issues using it, please post it as a new question.